# calling Fragment method from parent activity gives NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

When application is closed, I called fragment method from onCreate() of MainActivity onClick of Notification. But it gives NullPointerException()  says,

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'OneFragment.refreshMaterial(int, int, int, int)' on a null object reference '
```

I called fragment method from MainActivity as below,

```
OneFragment fragment = (OneFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_body);
fragment.refreshMaterial();
```

Comment: Obviously, `fragment` is null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your fragment is not null and is visible before using it

```
OneFragment fragment = (OneFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_body);

if(fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
      fragment.refreshMaterial();
```